# Multithreaded Network Scanner

Tags: c#, multithreading, network-programming, scanning

I've been trying to create an effective multi threaded network scanner using Backgroundworker in a for loop for each IP address in the range but have come across the following issues:

1) The UI thread always freezes intermittently, during which the memory usage greatly increases, sometimes up to 2-3GB for 255 IP Address scan.

2) Only at most 30-40 threads are produced even though there is no delay in the loop between creation of the new Backgroundworker for each IP.

The code for producing each thread is shown below. Is there a better way?

```
for (int i = 0; i < _deviceList.Count; i++)
            {
                _bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
                _bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
                _bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
                _bgw.DoWork += _bgw_DoWork;
                _bgw.ProgressChanged += _bgw_ProgressChanged;
                _bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += _bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;
                _bgw.RunWorkerAsync(_deviceList[i]);
            }
```

Comment: Is the UI thread the same thread that is creating all of the background processes? You may need to start a separate thread from the main one to kick of the work. Can you check the limit on your thread pool ? That may be why you are only getting 30-40. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.getmaxthreads(VS.95).aspx

Comment: `_bgw = new BackgroundWorker();`, the name `_bgw` looks like a field name, not a local variable. With it in a loop like that you will only ever have a reference to the last instance you created (if you care about having a reference). For example if you are calling `_bgw.CancelAsync()` elsewhere in the program only one worker will be canceled.

Comment: These threads are started from the main thread (its the button click event) but I have tried starting them from another thread too with the same results.
Also Scott I see what you are saying, but would changing it to a local variable fix the issues?

Comment: Guys thanks for your comments. I took both on board and now use a Dispatchertimer to create each thread with a delay of 200ms and made the _bgw a local variable. It seems to work much more reliably, more responsive and no memory blowout. Though I also limit the threads to 8 as increasing past that doesn't seem to improve performance...